# Does a levitating super conductor (Meissner effect) add weight?

Tags: superconductivity, levitation

A platform is placed on a weight scale. The scale reads 1kg. A super conductor weighing 100g is placed on top of the platform and it levitates such that no physical contact is made to the platform. What does the scale read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: if it reads 1kg, then we could send superconducting payloads, or payloads wrapped in superconductors, to space for no extra charge.

So it reads 1100 g. The magnetic field has to push back on the plate with 100 g$g$ of force.